# Return value from method (Java)

Tags: java, swing, variables

```
ok.addActionListener(new ActionListener ()
            {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                   //need to return value from method
                }
});
```

I created button and now I need to return value that I have in `actionPerformed`. How to do it?

Comment: You can't.  That callback will only run (maybe) after your method returns.

Comment: `//need to set an attribute of the class in which ok button is an attribute`

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to return a value from actionPerformed().  You can instead do something like:  `AClass.setReturnValue(whatever you wanted to return)` and then do an action base on that.